# iOS 14.0 how to control app clips size in flutter project

Tags: flutter, clip, ios14, apple-appclips

After creating an app clip target in existing flutter project, flutter.framework, flutter plugins and assets can't be split out to app clip target, app clip size has 10MB constraint. How to solve this problem?